# C# Mirror server relational model on client side

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, dto

Currently we are using a relational model stored in Entity Framework as a basis of our domain model. This model is sent over WCF and then recreated in code on the client side.

As an example I take the Student/Class case.

```
class Student {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Class {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

In WCF, we are only sending the `Name` and the `Id` (or list of `Id`s) to reduce the data transferred via DTO classes `ClassInformation` and `StudentInformation`.

```
class StudentInformation{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class ClassInformation {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<int> StudentIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then, of the client side, we manually match the `Student`s to their `Classe`s using the `Id`s. When a client removes a `Student` we manually remove it from it's `Class` if it is in any.

I've been looking for a solution that reduces that maintenance, for instance using an in-memory EF model and using that to recreate and cascade-edit the model but that too feel kind of quirky. Reflection could work as well, but maybe the is a framework that does just that.

My question is: is there a pattern or framework that reduces all the manual labour?